# Color Depth PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, pixelformat

I'm wondering what values to change in a `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` object to change the color depth.

According to the OpenGL wiki, this is how you'd create a `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` object for an OpenGL context:

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,    //Flags
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,            //The kind of framebuffer. RGBA or palette.
    32,                        //Colordepth of the framebuffer.
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    24,                        //Number of bits for the depthbuffer
    8,                        //Number of bits for the stencilbuffer
    0,                        //Number of Aux buffers in the framebuffer.
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0,
    0, 0, 0
};
```

But it has different variables effecting the color depth.

Which ones do I need to change to adjust the color depth accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

The first number, 32 in your particular example specifies the amount of color bitplanes available to the framebuffer. The other numbers define the numbers of bitplanes to use for each component. It's perfectly possible to fit a 5-6-5 pixelformat into a 32 bitplanes framebuffer, which is a valid choice.

When you pass a PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR to `ChoosePixelFormat` the values are takes as minimum values. However the algorithm used by `ChoosePixelFormat` may not deliver an optimal result for your desired application. It can then be better to enumerate all available pixelformats and choose from them using a custom set of rules.